# p-adic expansions and reciprocal

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Trying to get my head around p-adics,as i learn some more advanced number theory techniques but im stuck on an exercise.

If we let $\alpha = a_0 + a_1p + a_2p^2 + \dots = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_np^n$ be the expansion of a p-adic unit, then show that $\beta = -\alpha$ has expanson $\beta = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_np^n$ with $b_0 = p-a_0$ and $b_n = p-1-a_n$ for $n \geq 1$.

I then have to go onto to determine the first four digits of $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ where $\alpha = 2 + 1\cdot 5 + 3 \cdot 5^2 + 2 \cdot 5^3 \dots \in \mathbb{Z}_5$ (expressing it similarly as a 5-adic expansion).

I'm new to p-adic's as a concept. For the first question i tried to equate coefficients and then deduce each coefficient but i cannot seem to  arrive at the correct $b_n$.

Comment: Try calculating $\beta+\alpha$. All going well, you should get 0

Answer (score 1):

I still think the best way to think of $p$-adic integers, and the best way to do hand computations, is to use $p$-ary notation: binary if $p=2$, ternary if $p=3$, etc. Then the $5$-ary expansion of your number $\alpha$ is, rather,
$$
\dots2312;
$$
Notice that without the dots, this is just the $5$-ary expansion of the positive integer whose decimal expansion is $332$. The advantage of writing $p$-adic numbers this way is that to add, subtract, and multiply them, you use *exactly* the algorithms you learned in elementary school. The carries proceed right to left, same as in school, and all you need to have in front of you is a $p$-ary multiplication table and maybe also an addition table.

So, for instance, to calculate $-\alpha$, you put it underneath $\dots00000;$ and do your subtractions. First, you get $3;\,$, but you need a borrow and carry, and proceeding in the usual way, you find that $-\alpha$ has expansion $\dots2133;\,$. Alternatively, just as you may make change for $\$100$ by subtracting the price from $\$99.99$ and then adding a penny to the result, you may find $-\alpha$ by subtracting from $\dots4444444;\,$ and adding $\dots00001;$ to the result.

Division is a little trickier, since the elementary-school algorithm proceeds left to right, while $p$-adically, you must work right to left. If I were handier with LaTeX, I’d show you how to calculate $1/\alpha$, but I’ll have to leave it to you. (In case you’re still stumped, I can go into greater detail in a messy display.)